# Spark: dynamic schema definition out of csv file

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Receiving a schema information as csv file below. Assume i have around 100+columns

```
FIRSTNAME|VARCHAR2
LASTANME|VARCHAR2
MIDDLENAME|VARCHAR2
BIRTHDATE|DATE
ADULTS|NUMBER
ADDRESS|VARCHAR2
```

How to generate a schema dynamically in SPARK in this scenario?

Comment: Is the code you're posting some sort of header column or something? Please clarify what exactly it is, and if not clarify the exact format used.

Answer (score 0):

You can use string splitting and pattern matching assuming that the schema file is a validly formatted csv. Assuming that you already have the schema loaded as a single comma-separated string, the following will work:

```
def toSchema(str: String) = {
  val structFields = str.split(",").map{ s =>
    val split = s.split("\\|")
    val name: String = split.head
    val typeStr = split.tail.head

    val varCharPattern = "varchar[0-9]+".r
    val datePattern = "date".r
    val numPattern = "number".r

    val t = typeStr.toLowerCase match{
      case varCharPattern() => StringType
      case datePattern() => TimestampType
      case numPattern() => IntegerType
      case _ => throw new Exception("unknown type string")
    }
    StructField(name, t)
  }
  StructType(structFields)
}
```

You can add more types easily enough by just adding new cases to the pattern matching statement.